# Fixing list out of range error. Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random, int

I need a random number 1 - 3 to be generated. The error I'm getting is

> IndexError: list index out of range

My code is as follows:

```
weaponList = [0,1,2]
weapon2 = weaponList[random.randint(0,3)]
```

Comment: `randint` is inclusive, you want `(0,2)`.

Comment: or `random.randrange(len(weaponList))` or just `weapon2 = random.choice(weaponList)`

Comment: Thank you @MorganThrapp, thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
weapon2 = weaponList[random.randint(0,2)]
```

Should be the line
randint(int1,int2) is inclusive, so both numbers can be called.

Indices begin at 0, calling weaponList[0] will get you 0, which is at the zeroth index.

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are [zero indexed](http://python-history.blogspot.ch/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html). In your example:

```
>>> weaponList = [0,1,2]
>>> weaponList[0]
0
>>> weaponList[1]
1
>>> weaponList[2]
2
>>> weaponList[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Therefore, you have to pick a number between zero and two `random.randint(0,2)`, as `random.randint` [is inclusive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint).

An even cleaner solution was proposed by @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, added here for future  readers.

```
weapon2 = random.choice(weaponList)
```

This will select a random element from `weaponList`, so you don`t even have to struggle with indices.